# Centroid of point cluster points?

Tags: postgis

I have a table of point geometries like pointID, village and geom. I want to group the point by village and create a centeroid representing the village.

How do I write that query in PostgreSQL?

I am using PostgreSQL 9.6 with PostGIS 2.2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An easy way would be to collect (group them) all the points having the same village name attribute, create the polygons that enclose each group, then return the centroid of that polygon. For example:

```
SELECT village, ST_Centroid(ST_ConvexHull(ST_Collect(geom))) AS geom FROM your_table GROUP BY village;
```

Comment: I'd suggest omitting the `ST_ConvexHull` piece, which makes this solution very sensitive to outliers, and considering `ST_GeometricMedian` as an alternative to `ST_Centroid`.